# Pull changes down for remote branch linked to pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm maintaining an open source project

Someone has submitted a pull request which I've checked out locally using

`$ git fetch origin pull/105/head:emoji`

However, they've now updated their branch. How can I pull those latest changes down? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply do a git fetch and it will be updated.

GitHub use the ref to store pull requests and it will be updated just like any other ref in your repo.

If you have checked it out you can pull it or delete the local copy and checkout again, both ways will work.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was thinking but I couldn't tell if it was updating or not. Thanks, will accept your answer when I can in 12 minutes

Comment: You can always see it on the site as well.to verify but it just like any other refs so there is no problem with it.